# Spaces in the output from array values which I got with file()

Tags: php, arrays, file, csv

I tried everything I can find, but I am unable to get the result I'm looking for. I am taking two txt files, combining them together in every possible way with no duplicates and saving the output to a CSV file.

Everything works, except I can't get it to remove the middle space. For example:

list1.txt:

```
1
2
```

list2.txt:

```
dog
cat
```

The result I get is:

```
dog 1, dog 2, cat 1, cat 2, 1 dog, 2 dog, 1 cat, 2 cat
```

But I need (see spaces):

```
dog1, dog2, cat1, cat2, 1dog, 2dog, 1cat, 2cat
```

Code:

```
<?php

    $array1 = file('list1.txt');
    $array2 = file('list2.txt');

    $array3 = array();
    $array4 = array();

    foreach ($array1 as $key1)
    {

        foreach ($array2 as $key2)
        {
            $array3[] = $key1 . $key2;
            {
            $array4[] = $key2 . $key1;
            }
        }

    }

    print_r($array3);
    print_r($array4);


    $fp = fopen('combined.csv', 'w');

    fputcsv($fp, $array3);
    fputcsv($fp, $array4);

    fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: If there are no spaces in your files, then you also shouldn't have spaces in your output. The only thing I can imagine is, that you have new lines in your output, which can simply be solved by passing `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` as second argument in `file()` ; If you have spaces in your file just use `trim()` on your values.

Comment: try to use trim function. Trim function will remove the spaces
  $array3[] = trim($key1).trim($key2);

Comment: That did the trick, Rizier123! It was the line breaks in the file. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: All I needed to do was change these two lines: $array1 = file('list1.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); $array2 = file('list2.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

Comment: @Shawn FYI: You can self-answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and show what solved your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help from Rizier123, I solved the problem by simply changing lines 3 and 4 as follows:

```
$array1 = file('list1.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$array2 = file('list2.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

The problem was due to the line breaks in my two list files, as each keyword used in the arrays are on a separate line.

Comment: Good answer, that you don't only put the working code here, but also write what the problem was! So this can also be useful for future SO visitors.

Comment: Thanks, getting the hang of it. Still a newbie. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code

```
foreach ($array1 as $key1){
  foreach ($array2 as $key2){
    $array3[] = trim($key1).trim($key2);
    $array4[] = trim($key2).trim($key1);
  }
}
```

Or Use array_map function to trim all the elements of an array

```
$array = array_map('trim', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ravinder and Rizier stated, use trim(). So for example:

```
<?php

    $array1 = file('list1.txt');
    $array2 = file('list2.txt');

    $array3 = array();
    $array4 = array();

    foreach ($array1 as $key1)
    {
        foreach ($array2 as $key2)
        {
            $array3[] = trim($key1) . trim($key2);
            $array4[] = trim($key2) . trim($key1);
        }
    }
    print_r($array3);
    print_r($array4);

    $fp = fopen('combined.csv', 'w');

    fputcsv($fp, $array3);
    fputcsv($fp, $array4);

    fclose($fp);

?>
```

As a side note, it looks like you have a couple stray `{` and `}` in your code. You'll need to remove those for the code to complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `foreach` loop instead:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key1)
{

    foreach ($array2 as $key2)
    {
        $key1 = trim($key1);
        $key2 = trim($key2);
        /*
        If the above doesn't work, try this method:
        (If you use this method, you should delete your $array3 and $array4 assignments)

        $arrangement['array3'] = $key1.$key2;
        $arrangement2['array4'] = $key2.$key1;
        foreach($arrangements as $arrayName=>$str) {
            $str = preg_replace('#^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)$#', '', $str);
            $$arrayName[] = $str;
        }

        */
        $array3[] = $key1 . $key2;
        {
        $array4[] = $key2 . $key1;
        }
    }

}
```